# Openlayers - Multiple styles for different Geometry Types

Tags: openlayers-3

So I'm using a **single** vector layer where I put all of my :

- Points
- Polylines
- Polygons

This is my code :

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false });
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: // styleFunction or style or [style] don't know...
});
```

And I want to style the feature **based on their type**. I found this in the [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/apidoc/ol.style.html) but can't figure out how to use it :

> ...
>   A separate editing style has the following defaults:

```
 styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.POLYGON] = [
   new ol.style.Style({
     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
       color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5]
     })
   })
 ];
 styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.LINE_STRING] = [
   ...
 ];
 styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.POINT] = [
   ...
 ];
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the official drag/drop example -->[ol3 example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html)

It deals with every possible geometry.

So, declare your style object

```
    var defaultStyle = {
    'Point': new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.5)'
        }),
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#ff0',
          width: 1
        })
      })
    }),
    'LineString': new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#f00',
        width: 3
      })
    }),
    'Polygon': new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0,255,255,0.5)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#0ff',
        width: 1
      })
    }),
    'MultiPoint': new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255,0,255,0.5)'
        }),
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#f0f',
          width: 1
        })
      })
    }),
    'MultiLineString': new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#0f0',
        width: 3
      })
    }),
    'MultiPolygon': new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#00f',
        width: 1
      })
    })
  };
```

An then create your style function

```
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    var featureStyleFunction = feature.getStyleFunction();
    if (featureStyleFunction) {
      return featureStyleFunction.call(feature, resolution);
    } else {
      return defaultStyle[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
    }
  };
```

Finally, asign the style function to your vector layer

```
    map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({}),
      style: styleFunction
    }));
```

Comment: The problem with the style function is that it is called every time you move the map. But this is the method used in the official documentation, so I guess that's the way to do it. Thanks !

Comment: So you are fine with the answer but you dont really like that style function runs on every map move. I pressume you dont really like it 'cause this should give you bad performance. If I am right you can cache your styles and so improve the performance,. If thats the your case ask me to supply you with a code snip in order to cache your style.

Comment: It's ok, the `getStyleFunction` gets the style of the feature instead of assigning a new one each time the function is executed

Answer (score 3):

Get the geometry type and then apply the style based on the Geometry Type

```
  style:function(feature, resolution){
    var geom_name = feature.getGeometry().getType();
    return styles[geom_name];
  }
```

})

Find the demo link
https://plnkr.co/edit/kOzfXyv36UxXke8bALqU?p=preview